# Accidentally I deleted my instance-1

Tags: google-compute-engine

I accidentally deleted my instance-1 along with the boot disk, I would like to know if it is possible to recover in any way, considering that I used it as a server and I have a very important database for me, I have looked everywhere for some reverse the process, but I was not successful, the only thing I found, was the record of the exclusion, but there is no option to reverse the process, could you help me with this question?

Comment: You will need to restore from a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if you have removed a VM Instance without the "Deletion protection" enabled, you don't have any Snapshot, and the Boot disk was set as "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted", then is not possible to recover the data.

You might prevent accidental VM deletion by following the instructions mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion?hl=en_US&_ga=2.34495777.-1446863938.1557333849).